# Want to create a file name based on date range in groovy script

Tags: java, groovy

I am not much into programming and struggling with the below requirement.
On any particular date a file would be generate by a system and my script has to read the file name which would be example XYZ and rename is using groovy script to XYZ_ based on which date its run on. If it runs between 15th on this month and 14 of next month then the month name in the file would be of this month.
Example : If its run on 25th April 2021 then the file name should be : XYZ_P1_APR21_20210425777.csv since it falls between 15 Apr to 14 May 2021.

challenge is how do I put this in if/ switch condition since these conditions should be valid forever so in condition if I have to compare current date with the range then the range is also dynamic -since next year he range would be 15 Apr to 14 May 2022.

Please help.
Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no if/switch in this case.

you have to find/evaluate what was the month&year 14 days before the given date

```
'2021-04-25' - 14days = '2021-04-11'  ->  Apr 2021
'2021-04-15' - 14days = '2021-04-01'  ->  Apr 2021
'2021-04-14' - 14days = '2021-03-31'  ->  Mar 2021
```

the code to evaluate `the date 14 days ago` and format it looks simple:

```
def generateFileName(base, now=new Date()){
    def d14 = now - 14
    return "${base}_${d14.format('MMMyy')}"
}


assert 'XYZ_Mar21' == generateFileName('XYZ', Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','2021-04-14 23:59:59'))
assert 'XYZ_Apr21' == generateFileName('XYZ', Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','2021-04-15 00:00:00'))
assert 'XYZ_Apr21' == generateFileName('XYZ', Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','2021-04-15 01:00:00'))


println generateFileName('XYZ')
```

Comment: Thanks daggett, you are awesome .Your answered solved my query. Infact thanks I was heading for a very lengthy solution but yours is a very clean one!.Thanks.